# "Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows:..." when reimporting just exported products to empty database

Tags: import, importexport, export, sku

I exported all my single and configurable products to .csv and emptied my database of all products afterwards. I am now trying to reimport those same products using the just created .csv file. Unfortunately, I am getting the message:

```
Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows:...
```

followed by the list of skus, and followed by another message below:

```
Orphan rows that will be skipped due default row errors in rows
```

and then another list of skus. What does this mean, considering I have JUST created that same .csv from the currently working and functioning Magento? I also tried to completely empty the database from products and making only one configurable product with one associated simple product, with the same result (the error message `Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows`)  What can I do to mend this?

Answer (score 1):

You must import the simple product first and the configurable product after that. It sounds like the simple product cannot be find when the configurable product is imported.